# How do i invrease the CPU pool alocated to my aplication in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, directx, c++14, cpu-usage

i'm creating a game from an empty c++ project in Visual studio 2015, using direct X 12. but i'm running into the problem of something in the works keeping the program from using more than 20% of the CPU. and although this is great for small applications, it's useless for a game. how do i increase the amount of the CPU pool the application can use?

Comment: Without giving some details about the threading of your application, it's difficult to give advice. If you're using the Task Manager to measure performance, know that it divides CPU usage percentage over all cores. Thus, if you have 5 cores, and your process is using 100% of one core (it is single-threaded), then you will show 20% usage.

Comment: To answer your question for threading, i haven't manually scripted in any other threads, but i do have the `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` value in the `CoInitializeEx` all like so: `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);`

Comment: also, for processing performance measuring, i'm actually looking at the debug output graphs provided by MSVS 2015. you must forgive me, if i left anything out, i'm completely new at this and i thank you immensely!